# Jquery selector with $(this).val();

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to get rid of the line:

```
var zzz = $(this).val();
```

in

```
var zzz = $(this).val();
$('li.' + zzz).show();
```

It there a way to do that?

The full code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
   $("#fcheck input").click(function(){

    // If checked
    if ($("#fcheck input").is(":checked"))
    {
        //show the hidden div
        var zzz = $(this).val();
        $('li.' + zzz).show();
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise, hide it
        var yyy = $(this).val();
        $('li.' + yyy).hide();
    }
  });

});
```

The reason is that I have multiple input so I don't want the var to be set forever (maybe I should reset if after every call, but I don't know how to do that either).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The reason is that I have multiple input so I don't want the var to be set forever (maybe I should reset if after every call, but I don't know how to do that either).

Technically this variable isn't set forever once it leaves the scope of this function. You could simplify your code to what I have below using `toggle()` based on the `is(":checked")` result but what you have should work fine.

```
$("#fcheck input").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('li.' + $this.val()).toggle($this.is(":checked"));
});
```